# Why does jsonfn.expand include null values?

Tags: magnolia

I'm building up an array of JSON objects using [jsonfn](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/jsonfn) and rendering them on the JavaScript window object.

```html
[#assign json = []]
[#list articles as article]
  [#assign json += [jsonfn.from(article).add("categories", "title", "@name").expand("categories").inline().print()]]
[/#list]

<script>
  window.articles = [${json?join(",")}];
</script>
```

While effective, the expanded categories field (`expand("categories")`) sometimes includes null values.

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "displayName": "Example Category",
      "@name": "example-category"
    },
    null
  ],
  "title": "Example Article",
  "@name": "example-article"
}
```

This requires me to add an `instanceof Object` check when filtering in JavaScript so that I don't get a null error.

```js
export const filterArticles = (selectedCategory, articles) => {
  return articles.filter((article) => {
    return article.categories.find((category) =>
      category instanceof Object && category['@name'] === selectedCategory
    );
  });
};
```

Why does `jsonfn.expand` sometimes output null values? Why isn't there a null safety check to avoid including them in the rendered output?

Comment: This looks like more of an improvement request than an actual question, please create a ticket in the Magnolia issue tracking system.

Comment: Thanks @Ducaz035. How do I access the issue tracking system?

Comment: URL is: https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/ feel free to choose MAGNOLIA as the project if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JSONFN-5](https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/JSONFN-5) ticket. Should be working without printing `null`s as of version 1.0.9(-SNAPSHOT). Alternatively, pull the latest code from [github](https://github.com/magnolia-community/jsonfn) and build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Jan. We've pulled in the latest code. I'll let you know if there are any issues.

Comment: Can you make the release available via Nexus? We aren't currently able to access v.1.0.9 there.

Comment: Should be visible in nexus now.